# formatting date and timezone in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, lubridate

In my Rmarkdown document, I would like to display the date **and** the timezone in the header while omitting the actual time.

At the moment, the current code displays the date but leaves out the timezone:

```
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%d %B, %Y')`" 

> format(Sys.Date(), '%d %B, %Y')
[1] "19 March, 2018"

> Sys.time()
[1] "2018-03-19 22:22:11 EDT"
```

However, if I use `strsplit()` on `Sys.time()`, the time zone is omitted:

```
   > strsplit(as.character(Sys.time()), " ")
[[1]]
[1] "2018-03-19" "22:25:05"
```

Equally, this solution works in the console but throws and error in Rmarkdown:

```
paste(format(Sys.Date(), '%d %B, %Y'), tz(Sys.Date()))

Warning: Error in tz: could not find function "tz"
```

What would be the proper way to format `Sys.time()` or `Sys.date()` in Rmarkdown for the display to only appear as such:

```
"2018-03-19 EDT"
```

Comment: look at the code of print.POSIXct to track down where the EDT tag is being added. also, you should use strsplit on format(Sys.time())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `format` with timezone specification (%Z or %z)

```
format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %Z")
```